# Background-image only covers ~three quarters of page CSS

Tags: css

Dear fellow programmers

I have a little issue with my CSS code. I have an image as background and want it to cover the whole screen. The issue is that it only covers 4/3 of the background. There is a blank space at the bottom of my page.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://gymgames.ch/img/background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: fixed;
}
```

The image URL is working if you want to see the whole image.

The page URL is: https://gymgames.ch

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: cover will cover the element you spezified -> body if body is not 100% of your viewport height, you will see a blank space. Add `min-height: 100vh;` to your body and test it. Btw. `background-position: fixed` is not defined

Comment: Ok thats working fine. I am just wondering why it worked before. Anyway thank you. And btw the background-position: fixed was to see if it helps it. Now I removed it

Comment: One reason could be, that you have had more content in it? Default is, that body is only as high as you content inside it. If using min-height is not a solution for you (becouse of other side effects) you could use a fixed position div with 100vh and 100vw and z-index -1 with your background image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you specified, the background image is covering body, but body will not necessery be as height as your device.

You could add `min-height: 100vh;` to body and then it will work.

Btw. you are using `background-position: fixed;` which is an invalid value for the property, have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position). I think what you were looking for was center instad of fixed?

**EDIT:**

It it worked before, you have had enough content, so the body was high enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any other content on the page you can add something like

```
body{
min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Great, just what I needed to know! Thanks!